# Forwarding reference behavior with definite types

Tags: c++, c++14, forwarding-reference

Suppose I have a template class

```
template <typename T> class foo;
template <typename... Args>
struct foo<std::tuple<Args...>> {
  std::tuple<Args...> t;
  foo(Args&&... args): t{std::forward<Args>(args)...} { }
};
```

I understand that in this case `Args&&...` are rvalue references, and I could have just as well written `std::move` instead of `std::forward`.

I can also have a constructor with lvalue references, like so

```
foo(const Args&... args): t{args...} { }
```

The question is whether it's possible to get the same behavior as with forwarding references, but for definite types? The reason I want this is so I can used syntax like

```
foo bar({. . .}, {. . .}, . . ., {. . .});
```

This works if I define the `foo(Args&&... args)` constructor, but doesn't allow for a mixed scenario, where I want to initialize some of the member tuple elements with brace-enclosed initializer lists and have others copied from preexisting object instances.

Comment: It's not a "forwarding reference" if it isn't a forwarding reference. (Forwarding references require the template argument to be deduced.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure; there is a fancy and simple way.

The fancy way I will detail below.  First the simple way: take by value.

```
template <typename... Args>
struct foo<std::tuple<Args...>> {
  std::tuple<Args...> t;
  foo(Args... args): t{std::forward<Args>(args)...} { }
};
```

Really, just do this.  Forward is used to do the right thing if `Args` contains a reference.

Taking by value adds one move over perfect forwarding, but reduces the requirement for overloads exponentially.

---

This is the fancy way.  We type erase construction:

```
template<class T>
struct make_it {
  using maker=T(*)(void*);
  maker f;
  void* args;
  // make from move
  make_it( T&& t ):
    f([](void* pvoid)->T{
      return std::move(*static_cast<T*>(pvoid));
    }),
    args(std::addressof(t))
  {}
  // make from copy
  make_it( T const& t ):
    f([](void* pvoid)->T{
      return *(T const*)(pvoid);
    }),
    args(std::addressof(t))
  {}
  operator T()&&{return std::move(*this)();}
  T operator()()&&{ return f(args); }
};
```

This type erases construction by copy or move.

```
template <typename... Args>
struct foo<std::tuple<Args...>> {
  std::tuple<Args...> t;
  foo(make_it<Args>... args): t{std::move(args)()...} { }
};
```

It isn't perfectly transparent, but it is as close as I can get.

Double `{{}}` is required instead of single.  It is a user defined conversion, so another one will not implicitly be done.  We could add a universal ctor:'

```
  // make from universal
  template<class U>
  make_it( U&& u ):
    f([](void* pvoid)->T{
      return std::forward<U>(*(U*)(pvoid));
    }),
    args(std::addressof(u))
  {}
```

which works better if we add a sfinae teat that `U&&` can be used to implicitly construct `T`.

It has a few advantages, but they are marginal over just taking by value.  For example, in C++17 non-movable types can be perfect forward constructed in some cases.

Comment: Why is there unary `+` applied to lambdas? Explicit coercion to pointer seems to be superfluous here.

Comment: @yuri habit mainly?  I guess existence of broken Msvc makes it a bad idea.

Comment: @Yakk This is awesome. Thanks for the fancy answer. I have to confess, I don't understand the whole trick at a glance yet. What do you mean by "add a sfinae teat that `U&&` can be used to implicitly construct `T`"? That is the only functionality I'm asking for here. Can that be used with the `foo`'s constructor directly, if it's written as `template <typename... U> foo(U&&... u): t{std::forward<U>(u)...} {}`?

Comment: @SU3 use the simple solution.  Fancy was me being silly.  With fancy, do `{{blah...}}` and it works.  With simple, `{blah...}`.